# How to refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise

Tags: typescript, promise, sonarqube

I'm getting an `Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.` error on SonarQube on this code:

```
async getText(): Promise<string> {
    const element = await $(header.content);
    return await element.getText();
}
```

For this line `await $(locators.content)`

How can I solve this?

The solution on SonarQube is using something like:

```
let x = new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
await x;

let y = p ? 42 : new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
await y;
```

Tried to add the `$(locators.content)` inside a let or const but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete the `await`. `$` does not return a promise, so awaiting it is useless.

```
const element = $(header.content);
```

Comment: will it work on the same way by removing the `await`? I see that I use it also on the return line. So it's duplicated?

Comment: `will it work on the same way by removing the await` There are some nitpicky differences, but for your purposes it will work the same. If there are no promises, then you should not be awaiting. That goes for the second await as well.